# Rotación de logs en Nginx usando logrotate

Tags: nginx, logrotate, configuración

Debido a que los logs del proyecto están por superar los 4GB de tamaño, queremos empezar a usar [rotación de archivos](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/logrotation/). Para lograrlo hemos decidido usar [`logrotate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/logrotate.8.html).

Estos son los archivos que tengo en los logs:

```
$ ls -lh nginx-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data root 3,8G oct 27 14:03 nginx-access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root  30K oct 27 14:02 nginx-error.log
```

Como no estamos usando la ruta por defecto de los logs de Nginx (guardados en `/var/log/nginx/`), lo más sencillo era copiar el proceso actual de `logrotate` para Nginx y cambiarle la ruta para que apunte a los logs del proyecto:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/logrotate.d/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/gestagro
```

Luego de editar la ruta, el archivo contiene lo siguiente:

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/gestagro 
/home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

Normalmente, estos scripts deberían conrrer con el daily CRON, pero es posible forzar la ejecución. Esto es lo que me arroja:

```
$ sudo logrotate -f  /etc/logrotate.d/gestagro 
error: skipping "/home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-access.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
error: skipping "/home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-error.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
```

Tomando la sugerencia de `logrotate` agregué la directiva `su` al final para indicar el usuario y grupo que se debe usar para la rotación y para que coincida con el usuario y grupo actual de los archivos (`www-data:root`):

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/gestagro 
/home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data cesar
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
    su www-data root
}
```

Si intento nuevamente:

```
$ sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/gestagro 
error: failed to rename /home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-access.log to /home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-access.log.1: Permission denied
```

A pesar de que estoy usando el usuario `www-data` y el grupo `root` me arroja el error al tratar de renombrar el archivo.

Es la primera vez que uso `logrotate`, ¿qué me está faltando para lograr la rotación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logrotate` se está quejando de que los permisos de la ruta hasta el fichero de log son demasiado amplios. El directorio `/home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/` tiene permisos de escritura o para todo el mundo, o para un grupo distinto del grupo `root`.

El resultado es que cualquiera que pueda modificar ese directorio, o cualquier directorio padre de ése, puede engañar a `logrotate` sustituyendo algunas de las entradas de la ruta `/home/cesar/Development/Work/gestagro/logs/nginx-*.log`. Dependiendo de la configuración de `logrotate`, esto puede usarse para realizar algún tipo de ataque. Por ejemplo, si se hubiera usado la opción `copytruncate` sin la opción `su`, sería trivial crear un enlace a `/etc/passwd`, y causar que `logrotate` truncara ese fichero.

La opción `su`, que permite restringir los permisos con los que `logrotate` manipula ficheros, y la comprobación de que el directorio no tenga permisos de escritura demasiado amplios, se añadieron en respuesta a una serie de [vulnerabilidades](http://openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/03/04/16)<sup>enlace en inglés</sup>.

Puedo recomendar tres configuraciones distintas, por orden de preferencia:

- Ejecutar una instancia dedicada de `logrotate` como `www-data:adm`. El directorio con los logs deberá pertenecer a `www-data:adm` (para permitir a `www-data` crear ficheros de log, si no existen), y todos los directorios superiores hasta llegar al raíz, deberán pertenecer a `www-data:adm` o `root:root`.
- En vez de usar una instancia dedicada de `logrotate`, usar la directiva `su`, para que `logrotate` actúe temporalmente como `www-data:adm` cuando manipule los ficheros de log de nginx. El resto de requisitos son como la opción anterior. Un fallo de seguridad en `logrotate` podría ser usado para conseguir permisos de `root`.
- Dejar que `logrotate` actúe como `root`. El directorio de logs, y todos los directorios superiores hasta llegar al raíz deben pertenecer a `root:root`. nginx no podrá crear ficheros de log, por lo que deberán estar creados antes de arrancar nginx. Un descuido podría hacer que no se guardaran todos los logs de nginx.

En todos los casos, se recomienda usar los mínimos permisos posibles, que podrían ser 0750 o incluso 0700 para directorios, y 0640 o incluso 0600 para los propios ficheros.

En resumen, la ruta completa hasta los ficheros que `logrotate` vaya a tratar, debería tener unos permisos estrictos, para evitar que alguien pueda aprovecharse para truncar/modificar/llenar de basura comprimida cualquier fichero al que `logrotate` pueda acceder, posiblemente llevando a una escalada de privilegios completa.

Comment: Según lo que estoy tratando de hacer, ¿cuál sería la solución?

Comment: Darle permisos adecuados a todos los directorios de la ruta. Si eso no es posible, cambiar la ruta de logs a otro sitio. La situación ideal sería ejecutar una instancia de `logrotate` como `www-data:adm`, y que sólo `www-data:adm` tenga permisos de escritura en el directorio padre, y `www-data:adm` o `root:root` tengan permisos de escritura en los directorios superiores. En vez de crear una instancia dedicada de `logrotate`, se puede usar la directiva `su`, para conseguir algo parecido.